# Mocking HttpClient in a Custom API Service with Caching

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying writing some tests in Jasmine and I wanted to mock the HttpClient in my custom api service but I am getting an error. Specifically I think it is because of how I wrote my API service. I call the endpoint, and then I cache the result in a behavior subject. I return the behavior subject instead of the http request observable.

Here is my service code:

```
getData(binnum, xaxis, yaxis, numLines, selectionId, zoom = false) {
   let key = "x" + xaxis + "y" + yaxis + "bin" + binnum + "lines" + numLines;

   let cachedItem = this.cache[key];
   if (cachedItem != null) {
     console.log("cached item");
     return cachedItem.bs;
   }

   let bs = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
   this.binCache[key] = { bs: bs, ts: new Date().getTime() };

   let url = environment.apiEndpoint + 'bins?binnum=' + binnum + '&xaxis=' + xaxis + '&yaxis=' + yaxis;

   let obsv = this.http.get(url);
   obsv.subscribe((data: Array<any>) => {
     bs.next(data);
   })
   return bs;
 }
```

Here is my test code:

```
it(`should issue a request`,
   async(
      inject([CustomDataService, HttpTestingController], (service: CustomDataService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
         service.getData(200, 1, 2, 100, 0, false).subscribe();
         backend.expectOne({
            method: 'GET'
         });
      })
   )
 );
```

I get the error: 
**Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: GET, URL: (any)", found none.**

If I mock only the HttpClient it works:

```
it(`should issue a request`,
   async(
      inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
         http.get('/foo/bar').subscribe();
         backend.expectOne({
            method: 'GET'
         });
      })
   )
 );
```

How do I mock the http request in my CustomDataService? Do I need to separate my API service from my caching code?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#expecting-and-answering-requests

Comment: That resource does't help. As I said before, I was able to get mocking the HttpClient alone to work. My specific question is about why it doesn't work with my caching. I have edited my question.

Comment: I would suggest you to largely refactor your code is your intent is to make that service testable; extract the cache into a self-contained service, manage it through a HttpInterceptor and dont subscribe inside of your service call. One you get that done, the testability of your code will improve.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was recommended above to refactor my code so to use a caching service and an HttpInterceptor to manage it. Unfortunately I need to cache only certain API calls and the interceptors intercept everything. I didn't want to write code checking routes in the interceptor.

My original solution was modeled after something like [this](https://medium.com/@garfunkel61/https-medium-com-garfunkel61-angular-data-provider-services-in-memory-data-cache-c495a0ac35da). So in my solution I extracted the API call into its own service which my getData() function above uses. I can now mock out the HttpClient.

I am new to testing in Angular, but found an answer to what I originally wanted: a way to mock my call to the backend and return custom data. Here is the test I wrote:

```
it('Mocking a call to the backend', () => {

 // spyOn lets you mock a function call return a mock data
 spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue(of({ test: 2 }));
 renderManager.calculateThings(myService);

 // Check that it was called
 expect(myService.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

I know it is a little strange to be passing in an API service through a function, but my scenario warranted it.